# PagerSlidingTabStrip error when open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, pagerslidingtabstrip

When I import the "library" folder of PagerSlidingTabStrip to eclipse, there are already (many) errors in PagerSlidingTabStrip.java

I am new to android development so I wonder if I did something wrong

What I did:

1. Download PagerSlidingTabStrip from github
   (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip), by pressing
   "Download ZIP" on the right side of the the page
2. In Eclipse, right click on Package Explorer and choose Import
3. Choose "Existing Android code into workspace"
4. Select the "library" folder (not the whole
   "PagerSlidingTabStrip-master" folder which has just downloaded, just
   the "library" folder in it) by pressing "Browse" button

then the library is import but many errors exists in PagerSlidingTabStrip.java

I found this library should be useful for me but cannot even import the library to my project.

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to exaclty use the same Sample or any other is fine ?

Comment: Mostly you don't have the support library on your `libs` folder and also check the particular Android SDK version is installed to build the project.

Comment: I don't need the sample, I just want to implement the "action bar tab sliding effect" to my tabs

Comment: @intrepidkarthi, do u mean I need some update from Android SDK Manager?

Comment: yes. Check whether you have the SDK installed on your machine which that project uses.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi, no luck. I have the latest SDK but same errors exist

Comment: If you are unable to import, then you already have one more project on your workspace with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem , and found the solution.

go to your pagerslidingtabstrip prroject properties, then java build path and then order and export (on the right). check if android-support-v4.jar is present and selected ? if it is not there then go to libraries, then add external jar and then add from your sdk folder.